Почему виджет группы вк не растягивается на всё доступное пространство
Пишу сайт. Туда нужно внести виджет групп вк. B столкнулся с проблемой, что виджет не расстягивается на всё ему доступное пространство (на скриншоте снизу видно. Новое доступное пространство идет до смены цветов и линий)

Такая структура:
<div class="left-menu">
    <div class="left-menu-header">
        <div class="left-to-right"></div>
        <h4 class="left-menu-header-text">Мы вконтакте</h4>
        <div class="right-to-left"></div>
    </div>
    <div id="vk_groups">
        <script type="text/javascript" src="{% static "assets/js/vk-widget.js" %}"></script>
    </div>
</div>

Такие стили:
#vk_groups {
    padding: 0;
    margin: 0 auto;
    min-width: 100%;
    max-width: 100%;
}

#vk_groups > iframe {
    max-width: 100% !important;
}

Вот что в режиме разработчика в браузере:

При этом я заметил, что если отключить width: calc(25%) то пространство вокруг сжимается до размера виджета.
Вот js код запроса виджета:
function vk_widget() {
    VK.Widgets.Group("vk_groups", {
        mode: 3,
        height: 600,
        width: "auto",
        no_cover: 1,
        color1: "#0D0D0D",
        color2: "#ffffff",
        color3: "#0b92ad"
    }, циферки группы);
}

window.addEventListener("DOMContentLoaded", function () {
    vk_widget()
},true)

Скриншот побольше

Стили всей левой колонки
.left-column {
    width: 25%;
    color: var(--text-color);
    background-color: var(--left-menu-color);
    filter: drop-shadow(0px 4px 4px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.25));
    padding-top: 10px;
    border-top-left-radius: 10px;
}


@media (max-width: 800px) {
    .left-column {
        display: none;
    }
}


.left-menu > h4 {
    font-size: 1.5vw;
    text-align: center;
    text-transform: uppercase;
    margin-top: 3vh;
    color: #979797 ;
    border: 1px solid #303030;
    border-right-color: transparent;
    border-left-color: transparent;
    padding: 15px;
    font-family: "Montserrat", sans-serif;
    font-weight: bold;
    font-style: normal;
    font-optical-sizing: auto;
}

.left-menu-header-text {
    text-transform: uppercase;
    color: var(--text-color2);
    font-weight: bold;
    margin: 0;
}

.left-menu-header {
    display: flex;
    justify-content: space-between;
    align-items: center;
}

.left-to-right, .right-to-left {
    flex-grow: 1;
    flex-shrink: 0;
    height: 0.7svh;
}

.left-to-right {
    background: linear-gradient(90deg, #303030 0%, rgba(47.81, 47.81, 47.81, 0) 100%);
}

.right-to-left {
    background: linear-gradient(270deg, #303030 0%, rgba(47.81, 47.81, 47.81, 0) 100%);
}



h1 {
    overflow: hidden;
    text-align: center;
}

h1::before,
h1::after {
    background-color: #000;
    content: "";
    display: inline-block;
    height: 1px;
    position: relative;
    vertical-align: middle;
    width: 50%;
}

h1::before {
    right: 0.5em;
    margin-left: -50%;
}

h1::after {
    left: 0.5em;
    margin-right: -50%;
}


#vk_groups {
    padding: 0;
    margin: 0 auto;
    min-width: 100%;
    max-width: 100%;
}

#vk_groups > iframe {
    max-width: 100% !important;
}

Скриншот блока в режим разработки. Он растянут на всё доступное пространство. Однако вк виджет не расстягивается.


А можно скриншот побольше и стили выложите пожалуйста полные, то есть всего блока левой колонки

@LureRed добавил

Судя по Вашему же скриншоту, на iframe есть инлайновые стили, если это скриншот iframe элемента, конечно же, к тому же, указание max-width: 100% !important; не растягивает сам элемент на всю ширину, а просто указывает, какая ширина может быть максимальной для данного элемента.

собственно ответ в последней строчке, добавьте width:100%; в стили #vk_groups > iframe, как то так. #vk_groups > iframe {max-width:100% !important; width:100%;}

@LureRed нет, это не помогло. Всё так же не растягивается на полную

@FroggerProgger инлайн стили всегда имеют приоритет над стилями в CSS файле, попробуйте добавить !important к width, чтобы было width: 100% !important;. И не мешало бы увидеть к какому элементу относится то что Вы привели как скриншот к цитате: "Вот что в режиме разработчика в браузере"

@Simon попробовал  width: 100% !important; не помогло. "Вот что в режиме разработчика в браузере"  - относится к элементу ```#vk_groups``.  Который представлен в html выше того фрагмента.

либо копать выше, попробовал все куски хтмл и цсс что вы дали все работает виджет тянется на всю ширину колонки

@LureRed похоже дело в самом виджете или моем js коде для запроса виджета. Так как сам блок растягивается. Добавил скриншот.

@LureRed слушайте. И вправду. Решил проблему. Проблема была в том, как я запрашиваю виджет. Функция window.addEventListener("DOMContentLoaded", function () {     vk_widget() },true) Создавала такой эффект. После удаления функции и выставления просто vk_widget(). Проблема решилась. Большое спасибо вам за помощь

Решение оказалось достаточно необычным. В проблеме была виновата функция
window.addEventListener("DOMContentLoaded", function () {
    vk_widget()
},true)

Вероятно из-за того, что страница не успевала полностью прогрузить контент, блок создавался на меньший объем.
Рабочий код:
function vk_widget() {
    VK.Widgets.Group("vk_groups", {
        mode: 3,
        height: 600,
        width: "auto",
        no_cover: 1,
        color1: "#0D0D0D",
        color2: "#ffffff",
        color3: "#0b92ad"
    }, 222879328);
}

vk_widget()

Теперь всё хорошо функционирует

